# Better TreeView for Windows Forms - .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, winforms, forms, treeview

Is there a better **free** TreeView control that exists for Visual Studio 2008 / .NET 3.5?

I believe I need something a little more powerful than the out-of-the box version. I'm not exactly sure for what yet but I thought I'd ask quickly before I get too far in to my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[TreeViewAdv](http://treeviewadv.sourceforge.net/) seems to be pretty nice. It is described with the following features on SourceForge.net:

- Extensible advanced TreeView.
- 100% management C# code.
- Features: Model/View architecture.

  - Multicolumns.
  - Multiselection.
  - Different controls for each node: CheckBox, Icon, Label ...
  - Drag&Drop highlighting.
  - Load on demand.
  - Incremental search.

We will most likely use this in one or two occasions in an upcoming project, IIRC.

HTH

Comment: This is what I was looking for. While I'm not sure if it will work for my particular application I'm going to accept this as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I came across this post looking for a better TreeView.  I couldn't find much documentation on the the SourceForge page from the answer, but I did find a Code Project version that has a nice write up about the design and how to use some more advanced features at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14741/Advanced-TreeView-for-NET

Answer (score 0):

I would be wary with what you are going to use for a tree view control, make sure to test the amount of memory they consume vs speed of drawing.

We are having problems at work with the treeview control (made by Crownwood Software, called DotNetMagic) as it is causing memory leaks a lot, although its speed of drawing is *very* quick.

Most component vendors supply trials, so make good use of those! here are some to help you on your way:

[C1 Controls](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioWinForms/)
[DotNetMagic](http://www.dotnetmagic.com/features_treeControl.html) (but beware of the memory in this one, check for yourself, it still might be suitable)

**Edit:** Sorry, missed the free bit, sorry